# ngOnInit is not calling on route change

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular8, angular-routing, angular-router

I am using the dynamic loading of modules. Each module has only a single component is it.

My project structure is like that,

App Module -> Pages Module -> Lazy loaded modules (Student, Teacher).

Whenever both of the modules are loaded, ngOnInit is not called again.

I have tried `this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false` but unfortunately that didn't work.

Please help me to guide that what I am doing wrong with the code. I have already spent 3+ days on this issue and nothing helped me out of this problem.

Comment: what does your code look like? if you're routing to a component that is already loaded, the ngOnInit will not fire. it only fires when the component initially loads and routing a component to itself is not an exception.

Comment: Please share the code that is in the ngOnInit. Maybe it should live in another lifecycle hook.

Comment: Where sis you put `this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => false` it should be in constructor

Comment: Make sure your component class implements onInit before you use ngOninit.

Comment: @T.vandenBerg 
`export class PrescriptionComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(){}
ngOnInit(){
//my http call
}
`

Comment: @Lud Yeah I have put that line of code in my constructor

Comment: @rhavelka then what should I do for that? I have a scenario to call an HTTP request every time when a component is called over the route